# Error: Cannot find module, Nodemon crashes

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I am new with NodeJS and Express. I heard about nodemon and was trying to run it. But got an error. I tried solution from github, stack but nothing seems to work.

When I run `node app.js` it works properly and even `localhost:3000` responds to it.

But specifically nodemon dont seem to work. I have installed it globally.

And please believe me when I say that I visited all the stackoverflow pages that has solution for this issue. But none seems to work. I installed Nodejs again. I have reinstalled node_modules many time.
And tried to change `scripts{}` in package.json as said on those pages.

```
{
  "name": "prac-mysql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Connecting MySQL NODEjs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Above is the initial code as how it was. Please help me. Thank you so much.

(I am using it on windows system)

[image: This is the error I get]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot I can see that you're using minGW. On their official [website](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) it is stated:

> MinGW may have problems with paths containing spaces, and if not,
>   usually other programs used with MinGW will experience problems with
>   such paths. Thus, we strongly recommend that you do not install MinGW
>   in any location with spaces in the path name reference. You should
>   avoid installing into any directory or subdirectory having names like
>   "Program Files" or "My Documents", etc.

So probably this is not an issue with `nodemon` itself but with the underlying resolving of the path. Try using different directory names without spaces or executing nodemon from cmd/powershell.

EDIT:

The problem is that you're running `nodemon` without specifying any file and it will try to look for the `main`-file that you set in your package.json. Since you've set it to `index.js` and such file does not exist, the command fails. Changing `main` to `app.js` in your package.json should fix the issue.

Comment: Are we talking about only MinGW? If we are MinGW path is `D:\Software\MinGW\bin`
Is this ok?

Comment: No, I meant the project's path where your `index.js` file resides, i.e. `D:\New folder\New folder (2)`

Comment: I changed folder names. But it still shows this. `Error: Cannot find module 'D:\New_folder\Prac\index.js'`

Comment: Wait you wrote it works if you run `node app.js` -> so your main file is `app.js`, not `index.js`. Change it in the package.json. Alternatively try running it with `nodemon app.js` :)

Answer (score 0):

The error might get resolved by using ../

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).